# After running ipconfig to change ip, port forward doesnt work

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ipconfig

I ran the command `sudo ipconfig eth1 192.168.1.5 up` To change my server's ip to 192.168.1.5. However upon connecting to it from the external IP (I updated the port forwarding), it does not work. However the internal ip does. I could connect to it through the external ip before the command was run.

[image][image][image]

Comment: More information about the router being used is required to help.

Comment: It is the netgear WNR1000v3

Comment: Why did you change the ip through the operating system instead of changing what address woucl be assigned through the router's control panel?  I should point out a computer within a local network is not able to know whats its external ip address is in most cases.  If somebody outside of your network can't connect then there is indeed a configuration problem.